# Why seven (7) spaces is used when nesting code fragment to the list item?

Tags: markdown, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

Below is a fragment or markdown document, which renders normally here and in  ReText:

```
# Test

1. list item

    text in list item - line 1 (4 spaces)

        code in list - line 1 (8 spaces)
        code in list - line 2 (8 spaces)

    text in list item - line 2 (4 spaces)

1. list item
```

but in RStudio and by `pandoc` itself it [renders](https://pandoc.org/try/?text=%0A%23+Test%0A%0A1.+list+item%0A%0A++++text+in+list+item+-+line+1+(4+spaces)%0A%0A++++++++code+in+list+-+line+1+(8+spaces)%0A++++++++code+in+list+-+line+2+(8+spaces)%0A%0A++++text+in+list+item+-+line+2+(4+spaces)%0A%0A1.+list+item&from=markdown&to=html4) with extra space in the left side of each code line in HTML:

> [image: 8 eight spaces code block inside list item - HTML output]

and in DOCX:

> [image: 8 eight spaces code block inside list item - DOCX output]

So it seems that RStudio and `pandoc` need 7-spaces indent for correct rendering of the code in the list element.

Why this happen? Is it a bug or feature?

---

Below is the same code fragment rendering as SA does:

## Test

1. list item

   text in list item - line 1 (4 spaces)

   ```
   code in list - line 1 (8 spaces)
   code in list - line 2 (8 spaces)
   ```

   text in list item - line 2 (4 spaces)
2. list item

---

And as you can see it do not have extra spaces in the left side of code lines.
Other rendering from [babelmark2](https://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=%23+Test%0A%0A1.+list+item%0A%0A++++text+in+list+item+-+line+1+(4+spaces)%0A%0A++++++++code+in+list+-+line+1+(8+spaces)%0A++++++++code+in+list+-+line+2+(8+spaces)%0A%0A++++text+in+list+item+-+line+2+(4+spaces)%0A%0A1.+list+item) are also available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [guide](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html%23raw-tex):

> A block quotation is one or more paragraphs or other block elements
>   (such as lists or headers), with each line preceded by a > character
>   and an optional space. (The > need not start at the left margin, but
>   it should not be indented more than three spaces.)

First 4 Spaces will put the text in the list and 3 more spaces will transform it to block in the list. (4+3 =7)